# Show that $1^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} +\ldots + (p-1)^{p-1} \equiv -1 \mod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that 
>   $$1^{p-1} + 2^{p-1} +\ldots + (p-1)^{p-1} \equiv -1 \mod p$$

So, I use Fermat's little theorem, that is if $p$ does not divide $a$, then $a^{p-1}$ is congruent to $1$ (mod $p$). But I'm still confused. If $1^{p-1}$ is congruent to $1$ (mod $p$), $2^{p-1}$ is congruent to $1$ (mod $p$), and $p$ does not divide $p-1$, so $(p-1)^{p-1}$ is congruent to $1$ (mod $p$). How does that equal $-1$ (mod $p$)?

Comment: This is the third question you've asked in 20 minutes, none of which have any indication of your knowledge or understanding of the problem; please give a brief description of your thoughts on the subject.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website. It was suggested by a friend as a way to get help. And since I'm struggling in the class, I figured I would give it a try.

Comment: Asking homework questions is perfectly fine, but please don't just state the problem and leave it at that. Show your ideas and tell us what you *do* understand, since it gives a good starting point.

Comment: SO, I use fermat's little theorem, that is if p does not divide a, then a^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p). But I'm still confused. If 1^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p), 2^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p), and p does not divide p-1, so (p-1)^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p). How does that equal -1 (mod p)

Answer (score 3):

$$k^{p-1}\equiv 1 \text{ mod p} \text{ , } \forall p\nmid k$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}k^{p-1}\equiv (p-1)\equiv -1 \text{ mod p}$$

Comment: SO, I use fermat's little theorem, that is if p does not divide a, then a^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p). But I'm still confused. If 1^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p), 2^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p), and p does not divide p-1, so (p-1)^(p-1) is congruent to 1 (mod p). How does that equal -1 (mod p)

Comment: @Kara thanks I made an error, it should be $1$ modulo $p$ you are correct, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Apply Fermat's little theorem to each term, then sum.

Comment: this is the question I just asked in my last comment

Comment: I do not understand how it sums to -1

Comment: $1+1+\cdots+1=p-1$, if there are $p-1$ summands.